# Search a range of text, if found, copy cells to another part of spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sorting, copy, vba

I'm new to making excel macros, so not sure how to code this. Basically, on run, I want to search a range of cells (in this case, A2-A25) for certain number ranges, (like 1700-1799, 2900-2999) and if found, copy/sort them in another place on the spreadsheet.

For example, the sheet (after run) would look like this:
1712
2983
2931
1723
1745

1712
1723
1745

2983
2931

Is a macro like this possible?

Comment: have you tried something so far? If not - [Macro Recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) is a good start for you.

Comment: Gary's Student got me exactly what I need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will put the results in columns **B** and **C**:

```
Sub GetValues()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v As Long
    Set A = Range("A2:A25")
    i = 1
    j = 1
    For Each r In A
        v = r.Value
        If v >= 1700 And v <= 1799 Then
            Cells(i, "B").Value = v
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If v >= 2900 And v <= 2999 Then
            Cells(j, "C").Value = v
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**:

This version stores the results in column **A** starting in **row #30** and **row #50** .................modify to suite your needs:

```
Sub GetValues()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v As Long
    Set A = Range("A2:A25")
    i = 30
    j = 50
    For Each r In A
        v = r.Value
        If v >= 1700 And v <= 1799 Then
            Cells(i, "A").Value = v
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If v >= 2900 And v <= 2999 Then
            Cells(j, "A").Value = v
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2**:

This version copies the entire rows:

```
Sub GetValues()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v As Long
    Set A = Range("A2:A25")
    i = 30
    j = 50
    For Each r In A
        v = r.Value
        If v >= 1700 And v <= 1799 Then
            r.EntireRow.Copy Cells(i, "A")
            i = i + 1
        End If
        If v >= 2900 And v <= 2999 Then
            r.EntireRow.Copy Cells(j, "A")
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this is very close to what I need and a good place for me to jump off of. Want to know if an adjustment is possible. Rather than copy the values to different columns, would it be possible to copy the row it finds that value in (from A to J) to a row lower down on the spreadsheet (say, row 30)?

Comment: You absolutely rock. I can't even express how much trouble you just saved me. This is perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: One more adjustment if possible. I want to copy the whole row, not just the cell the number was found in. Such as, if in Row 2 it finds 2912, it copies A2 - J2 down to row 30.

Comment: **Give me about 1 hour**

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a macro you can use this array formula:

```
=SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$25>=1700)*($A$1:$A$25<=1799);$A$1:$A$25;"");ROW(A1))
```

write, for instance in c1, and copy down to get all the values.

You need Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace ";" by ","